# Two columns Bootstrap 4 nav-tabs

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm looking for a way to make a two-columns Bootstrap (4) tabs (or pills). The render I would like to have should look like this:

[two-columns bootstrap4 tab goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqz8f.png)

An icon on the left, and a title + subtitle on the right side of the tabs.

Does somebody have a snippet somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: You may get an answer sooner if you post some code of any current attempt of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my solution, using only Bootstrap 4:

I used the [Nav component](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/), inserting a parent div and two child ones. For the parent div, I used the [flexbox utilities](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/) for Bootstrap 4.

Cheers :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 4</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
          <div>
            <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-2x pr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h4 class="m-0 p-0">Title</h4>
            <p class="m-0 p-0">Subtitle</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for BlackNina, thank your very much!